# How to install OpenNTF Domino API 3.1.0 in Eclipse Mars for use with OSGi plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, lotus-domino

I wanted to try using ODA when doing OSGi plugin development and found this example by Paul Withers:

http://www.intec.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/com.paulwithers.demoServlet.update.3.0.zip

Problem after importing project is that ODA Dependencies (required plug-ins) are not resolved for 'org.openntf.domino' and 'org.openntf.domino.xsp'.

Trying to install ODA 3.1.0 in Eclipse Mars yields the following error:

> Missing requirement: OpenNTF Domino API requires 'com.ibm.icu.base 0.0.0' but it could not be found

How to resolve?

Best regards from Ove

Comment: I managed to find the com.ibm.icu.base plugin in this repository:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20160221192158/repository/
Now however I get:  Missing requirement: OpenNTF Domino API 3.1.0.201701051852 (org.openntf.domino.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201701051852) requires 'com.ibm.commons 9.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it best to not actually install ODA into Eclipse, but instead add it to the Target Platform. What I do nowadays is, with an Eclipse workspace dedicated to XPages-targetted development, I create a new Target Platform definition in `Preferences - Plug-in Development - Target Platform` that points to each library I'm using, as well as the [Update Site for Build Management](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/IBM%20Domino%20Update%20Site%20for%20Build%20Management) IBM put together. For example, from one project I have:

[image]

That also helps for Maven builds, since then I can point to those repos from the pom and have a consistent Target Platform all around.

Comment: Really an eyeopener for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have XPages SDK installed? That will point to all the relevant Domino-related jar files.

If more discussion is needed, it may be best to ask in ODA arera of OpenNTF Slack Chat. If you're not already in there (I can't see your name) you can join at https://openntfslackin.mybluemix.net/